# Custom Manager not rendered properly after being added to a VerticalFieldManager in BlackBerry

Tags: java, blackberry

I have a VerticalFieldManager that renders a white round rectangle.

This is the code:

```
 VerticalFieldManager _vfmBackground = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | 
                Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH){
             public void paint(Graphics graphics)
                {
                    graphics.clear();
                    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    graphics.fillRoundRect(10, 10,460, 400, 25,25 );
                    super.paint(graphics);
                }

              protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
                {
                    int displayWidth = (Display.getWidth());
                    int displayHeight = (Display.getHeight());

                    super.sublayout( displayWidth, displayHeight);
                    setExtent( displayWidth, displayHeight);
                }

        };
```

Then I create a custom Manager class named BaseHeaderBlueScreen that renders a blue rectangle:

```
public void paint(Graphics graphics)
    {
     graphics.clear();
     graphics.setColor(610212);
     graphics.fillRect(20, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
     super.paint(graphics);
    }

    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
    {
        int displayWidth = (Display.getWidth()-40);
        int displayHeight = ((Display.getHeight()/2))-90;

        super.setExtent( displayWidth, displayHeight);
    }
```

Finally, I add that custom manager to the VerticalFieldManager with the white rounded rectangle:

```
BaseHeaderBlueScreen _vhbs = new BaseHeaderBlueScreen(textTop, textBottom, 0);
        _vhbs.setPadding(20,30,0,0);
        _vfmBackground.add(_vhbs);
```

This is how the blue rectangle should be displayed within the white rectangle.

[image]

But this is how the blue rectangle is currently being displayed (please note the gray space of its left side):

[image]

How should I do to render the blue rectangle exactly as desired (without the left gray border)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just unnecessarily making a call to `Graphics.clear()`.  `clear()` is meant to fill in the graphics area with whatever color is currently set as the background color.  Normally, you would use `clear()` like this:

```java
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    // calling clear makes the background gray
    g.clear();

    // now draw some text
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawText("hello", 20, 40);
}
```

From the [API docs for clear()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html#clear%28%29):

> Clears the entire graphics area to the current background color. Note that global alpha is not applied in this case.

But, you're calling `clear()` before you make any other calls.

So, just remove the two calls to `clear()` (although the one that's causing this particular problem is the call in `BaseHeaderBlueScreen.paint()`).